# Null exception been thrown when interacting with generated PowerShell report executed from context menu sitecore spe

Tags: powershell-extensions, content-editor, powershell

When the report is generated by the PowerShell script that is executed from the context menu within content-editor, it typically provides interaction features like sorting, export choices, and item navigation. But there's a problem I've encountered. In certain cases, I can interact with the generated report for more than ten minutes, but in other cases, it only takes less than two minutes before it throws a null exception that points to the SPE DLL.
The fact that this issue takes a different amount of time to happen each time it happens is confusing. Has anyone ever encountered a problem like this, and how did you solve it. Any pointers will be appreciated

**about to trigger the report**

[image]

**Screenshot of the report generated**

[image]

**Screenshot of the error thrown after a while**
[image]

Comment: Did this be any should cause by the HTTP session clearing out?